# Can other party members wield a warlock's pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, fighter

Lets say the group's Great Weapon Fighter and Bladelock have their weapons confiscated. Can the Warlock call his pact weapon and, assuming it is the type of weapon the Fighter uses mostly, give it to the Fighter for the Fighter to use in combat?

The rules say the pact weapon disappears if it is more than 5 feet away from the summoner for more than 1 minute. During this time can the Fighter use it?

Comment: This is also a great idea when fighting enemies with resistance to non-magical weapons if your fighter friend doesn't have one yet.

Comment: @DerekStucki That comment might be worth appending to your answer.  Up to you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Yes, other characters can wield it (within limits)

You cited the only relevant rule in your question. The warlock would have to either be within 5 feet of the weapon every minute, or resummon it frequently, but the passage quoted clearly allows the weapon to be away from the warlock for plenty of time to be useful in the hands of someone else.

Comment: To add, 1 minute equals 10 turns of melee.

Comment: @Escoce I think the exact wording would be "1 minute equals to 10 *rounds* of melee", as each creature has a turn in said rounds.

Comment: ...now I find myself thinking about how to cheese that.  Is there any way to have the resulting weapon benefit further from invocations?