# What ability score does a Hexblade's Pact Weapon use for attack and damage when wielded by another character?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, warlock, ability-scores, hexblade

I read [this question about other PCs using pact weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72334/can-other-party-members-wield-a-warlocks-pact-weapon) and realized that I'm not sure if the weapon would use the warlock's Charisma, or the other character's Strength/Dexterity for attack and damage rolls.

Now, the text of Hex Warrior says "when *you* attack with that weapon you can use your Charisma modifier..." Am I right in assuming that another character that uses the weapon (a barbarian, say) would use their ability scores, rather than the warlock's Charisma?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Are you asking about the Pact of the Blade feature's pact weapon, or the weapon(s) associated with the Hexblade's Hex Warrior feature (which says it also applies the same benefits to your pact weapons)? It looks like you're specifically asking about the latter, though your title mentions pact weapons in particular.

Answer (score 22):

### You're right: only the Hexblade can benefit from their own Hex Warrior feature

It's simply stated in the text you quoted - when **you** attack with the affected weapon, **you** can use your charisma bonus. The *Hex Warrior* feature doesn't say anything about what happens when someone else uses a Hexblade's weapon, so the normal rules must apply and they would use their appropriate ability score as usual when making attacks with the weapon.